# How to set the default color gradient in Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

In Julia's `Plots` package, I can change the color of a surface plot like this:

```
plot(mySurface,st=:surface,c=:blues)
```

How can I change the default color gradient so that I don't have to put the `c=:blues` every time?

(The relevant [Plots doc page](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/colors/) does not state how to modify the default.)

Answer (score 2):

I saw a possible solution here.
https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/87

```
with(c = :blue) do
plot!(rand(5))
plot!(rand(5))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

See the tip from the Julia Plots documentation:

> Tip: You can see the default value for a given argument with `default(arg::Symbol)`, and set the default value with `default(arg::Symbol, value)` or `default(; kw...)`. For example set the default window size and whether we should show a legend with `default(size=(600,400), leg=false)`.
>
> http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/basics/

Hence, you can set the default you want with

```
default(c=:blues)
```

Though you probably want to set a new default for `fillcolor` rather than `seriescolor` or its alias `c` since `seriescolor` will also affect color of other type of plots and you probably would not want that.

```
default(fillcolor=:blues)
```

The default will work so long as you do not set any other default or restart your Julia session.

If you want your new default to work even after restarting Julia you might want to try [`Requires.jl`](https://github.com/MikeInnes/Requires.jl) and your startup file (`~/.julia/config/startup.jl`) with something like the following,

```
using Requires
@require Plots="91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80" Plots.default(fillcolor=:blues)
```

where `91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80` is the UUID of `Plots.jl` package in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

You should either the `palette` or the `m` keyword as shown in [the examples](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/examples/gr/#colors):

```
y = rand(100)
plot(0:10:100, rand(11, 4), lab="lines", w=3, palette=:grays, fill=0, α=0.6)
scatter!(y, zcolor=abs.(y .- 0.5), m=(:heat, 0.8, Plots.stroke(1, :green)), ms=10 * abs.(y .- 0.5) .+ 4, lab="grad")
```